# Customize project information / fields on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

i wonder if it is possible in devops to customize the project information? I would like to add a field for responsible and some general information, but there is only the description fields.

any help appreciated, Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add a field for responsible and some general
> information, but there is only the description fields.

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently not supported in azure devops. The project summary page currently only supports the "`Add Project Description`" option, which includes selecting project README file or a project wiki.  For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/project-vision-status?view=azure-devops).

[image]

In addition, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Customization of project default screen (Project Summary page)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/customization-of-project-default-screen-project-su/409247). You can comment and vote it there. Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan.